# Why my LINK component does not render the component that match the URL? , it only changes the url on the browser

Tags: reactjs

Imports and PageNotFound component:
[image: Imports and PageNotFound component]

App main component:

[image: App main component]

Comment: I am using react-router-dom@5.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently an incompatibility between react-router-dom@5 and React 18

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include `path` prop to the route where you render `PageNotFound`.

Change

```html
<Route>
  <PageNotFound/>
</Route>
```

to

```html
<Route path="*">
  <PageNotFound/>
</Route>
```

Comment: That Route will render PageNotFound component when path does not match the ones declared already

Comment: @Roberto What do you mean?

Comment: If  you enter any path That is not ( path=‘/‘ or path=‘/gym’) pageNotFound component will be render on the browser.

Comment: Then what I struggle with is that from pageNotFound component I have a Link that doesn't work , I dont know why

Comment: In PageNotFound there is a Link to =‘/gym’ but it only change the url on the browser without render the component for to path=‘/gym’ Which is GymOption component.